# Unexpected behaviour of hash function when using set in a class

Tags: python-3.x, hash, set

I have 2 classes down below. Since only hashable objects could be stored in sets I define **hash** function for class Person. Everytime I add Person to group object **hash** function is called and generates hash using name only. Could someone explain to me, why when I add a p2 object with the same name as p1, but different age to group python still adds it to a group object even though 2 objects have the same hash. Shouldn't python when adding object to a set check hash and either add or replace an object? If I try to add a p3 object exactly the same as either p1 or p2 it will not be added.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __hash__(self):
        print(f'inhash: {self.name}, {self.age}, {hash(self.name)}')
        return hash(self.name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Person({self.name}, {self.age})>'


class Group:
    def __init__(self, group_name):
        self.group_name = group_name
        self.persons = set()

    def add_person(self, person):
        self.persons.add(person)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Group({self.group_name}, {self.persons})>'


p1 = Person('p1', 10)
p2 = Person('p1', 20)

print("persons p1, p2, p3:", (p1, p2))
group = Group('pp')
group.add_person(p1)
print(group)
group.add_person(p2)
print(group)
```

Comment: You need to implement `__eq__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs of `__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> **If a class does not define an `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either**; if it defines `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable as items in hashable collections. If a class defines mutable objects and implements an `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since the implementation of hashable collections requires that a key’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).

Emphasis mine.

You need to also supply a `__eq__` implementation for it to be able to properly differentiate objects.